# CPAN out-of-memory error after installing CSWpmtermreadlineg on Solaris

Tags: perl, cpan, readline

Is anyone having a problem with cpan unable to build anything after installing the Readline package on Solaris?

Found this but it doesn't help: http://cpanforum.com/posts/8958

This is on box with 32G!

Comment: Can you revert to an older version (say, [here](http://search.cpan.org/CPAN/authors/id/H/HA/HAYASHI/Term-ReadLine-Gnu-1.09.tar.gz))?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get CPAN to work again by installing Term::Readline.

But then I discovered cpanplus (command "cpanp"), a much better cpan shell!

Comment: Please do, without good bug reports things on rare platforms are seldom fixed. If you want assistance in isolating the appropriate component so that the bug report goes to the right place immediately, ask around on [cpan-discuss](http://lists.perl.org/list/cpan-discuss.html) and [MagNET #toolchain](http://irc.perl.org/).